# How can I limit regression output between 0 to 1 in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to detect the single pixel location of a single object in an image. I have a keras CNN regression network with my image tensor as the input, and a 3 item vector as the output.

**First item**: Is a 1 (if an object was found) or 0 (no object was found)

**Second item**: Is a number between 0 and 1 which indicates how far along the x axis is the object

**Third item**: Is a number between 0 and 1 which indicates how far along the y axis is the object

I have trained the network on 2000 test images and 500 validation images, and the val_loss is far less than 1, and the val_acc is best at around 0.94. Excellent.

But then when I predict the output, I find the values for all three output items are not between 0 and 1, they are actually between -2 and 3 approximately. All three items should be between 0 and 1.

I have not used any non-linear activation functions on the output layer, and have used relus for all non-output layers. Should I be using a softmax, even though it is non-linear? The second and third items are predicting the x and y axis of the image, which appear to me as linear quantities.

Here is my keras network:

```
inputs = Input((256, 256, 1))

base_kernels = 64 

 # 256
conv1 = Conv2D(base_kernels, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inputs)
conv1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
conv1 = Conv2D(base_kernels, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv1)
conv1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
conv1 = Dropout(0.2)(conv1)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

# 128
conv2 = Conv2D(base_kernels * 2, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool1)
conv2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
conv2 = Conv2D(base_kernels * 2, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv2)
conv2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
conv2 = Dropout(0.2)(conv2)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

# 64
conv3 = Conv2D(base_kernels * 4, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool2)
conv3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
conv3 = Conv2D(base_kernels * 4, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv3)
conv3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
conv3 = Dropout(0.2)(conv3)
pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)

flat = Flatten()(pool3)

dense = Dense(256, activation='relu')(flat)
output = Dense(3)(dense)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[output])

optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-4)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks! :)
Chris

Comment: I personally don't think pure CNN would be good at decide distance. can you show your network structure?

Comment: Thanks @appleapple, I've added my network to the question.

Comment: accuracy is not a good metrics, since your output are not all about classification. I would like to use the mae/mse metrics. and [split the output to 3 part](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models) to see the error for each part.

Comment: Splitting the output for each part sounds good. How do I do that?

Comment: the [link](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models) I provide has example, basically you have 3 out tensor (ex,dx,dy) and `model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[ex,dx,dy])`

Comment: and you can optionally apply `sigmoid` on first output

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sigmoid activation produces outputs between zero and one, so if you use it as activation of your last layer(the output), the network's output will be between zero and one.

```
output = Dense(3, activation="sigmoid")(dense)
```

Comment: This works, is there an approach to prevent NaN inside the last layer, if values get too small?

Comment: Using sigmoid is not good for regression as it is more biased towards 0 and 1 than the middle values (only good for classification). One should use an activation function like relu and restrict it to be less than 1.